# Разная высота блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Есть 6 блоков. У четных высота 270px, у нечетных - 300px. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы все блоки отображались независимо от разницы высоты, то есть блоки не были жестко привязаны к ряду?

[image: пример]

Comment: Покажите код, где Вы выставляете эти блоки.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: -20px auto 0;
  width: 246px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: silver;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 25px 5px -15px;
  height: 100px;
}

p:hover {
  background: blue;
}

p:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear: left;
}

p:nth-child(even) {
  height: 80px;
}

p:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

p:nth-child(6n + 6):last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p>
```